# Arbitrary pointer to unknown class function - invalid type conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, casting

I have a hack program; it injects some functions into a target process to control it. The program is written in C++ with inline assembly.

```
class GameProcMain {
 // this just a class
};

GameProcMain* mainproc; // there is no problem I can do =(GameProcMain*)0xC1EA90
```

Now I want to define a class function (which set ecx to class pointer) instead of writing assembly.

```
PPLYDATA GetNearblyMob(__Vector3* cordinate) {
    __asm {
    mov ecx, 0xC1EA90
    enter code here
    push cordinate
    mov edi, 0x4A8010
    call edi
    }
}
```

I want to define it and call it like.

```
PPLYDATA (DLPL::*GetNearblyMob)(__Vector3* cordinate);

mainproc->GetNearblyMob(ADDR_CHRB->kordinat)
```

When I try `GetNearblyMob=(PPLYDATA (DLPL::*)(__Vector3*)) 0x4A8010;`

It says something like `error: invalid type conversion: "int" to "PPLYDATA (DLPL::*)(int, int)"`

but I can do this to set the pointer:

```
void initializeHack() {
__asm {
LEA edi, GetNearblyMob
MOV eax, 0x4A8010
MOV [edi], eax
}
}
```

Now I want to learn "how I can set GetNearblyMob without using assembly and legitimately in C++".

Comment: You are probably not going to find much help here in getting your game cheating code to work.

Comment: what's wrong with cheating? Personally, I learned a lot of assembly learning to cheat in ZX-80 games.

Comment: msw, however my hack works and will work without this thing.. i just want to compiler generate the smart assembly code, not myself. because there is a lot of functions that i assemble, http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/3432/hackzv.jpg p.s hamster3null, thank you again, i learned assembly with cheating too, i can use a lot of debugger for cracking applications and hook directx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that member functions automatically get an extra parameter for the `this` pointer. Sometimes you can cast between member and non-member functions, but I don't see the need to cast anything.

Typically it's easier to reverse-engineer into C functions  than into C++. C typically has a more straightforward ABI, so you can keep the data structures straight as you work them out.

So, I would recommend

```
PPLYDATA (*GetNearblyMob)(DLPL *main_obj, __Vector3* cordinate) = 0x12345UL;
```

and then define your own function

```
class DLPL {
    GetNearblyMob( __Vector3* cordinate ) {
        return ::GetNearblyMob( this, cordinate );
    }
    // ... other program functions
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit surprised that it won't you cast like that.

You can try to do something like

```
GetNearblyMob=reinterpret_cast<PPLYDATA (DLPL::*)(__Vector3*)> (0x4A8010);
```

If that still does not work, try

```
*(int*)(&GetNearblyMob) = 0x4A8010;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
first is gives this error.
error: invalid type conversion: "int" to "PPLYDATA (DLPL::*)(int, int)"
1>   GetNearblyMob=reinterpret_cast<PPLYDATA (DLPL::*)(int, int)>(0x4A8010);

the second is gives expression is non editable, when i remove & keyword it gives invalid type conversion: "PPLYDATA (DLPL::*)(int, int)" to "int"

but it works on non-class function pointer...
int (__stdcall* GetCurrentZone)()=(int (__stdcall *)())0x49B070;

Comment: p.s. i want to click the answer is useful button but it doesn't work on my account yet:)

Comment: The second option works for me in gcc. "Expression is non editable"? That is a strange error. What is the exact wording? Maybe the function pointer is declared as const?

Comment: wow sorry, yes. i was tried (int)(&GetNearblyMob) = 0x4A8010; i forgot to * operator :D \*(int\*)(&GetNearblyMob) = 0x4A8010; it works thank you so much !